# Configuring S3 bucket access by user and IP

Tags: amazon-s3

Thanks to [Amazon S3: Grant anonymous access from IP (via bucket policy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141362/amazon-s3-grant-anonymous-access-from-ip-via-bucket-policy) I was able to allow anonymous uploads to my bucket. But only to figure out, that I don't have access rights to the uploaded files. I can delete them, but cannot open them or change any security settings. Obviously that's not what I wanted to have!

My use case is the following:

There are some users like myself, which should be able to access the bucket from any machine. Those users will use their access keys. And there are some scripts on some well known machines (i.e. IP numbers of EC2 instances), which should be able to access the bucket without deploying credentials to them. They should be granted access by their IP number.

How do I configure S3 security in that scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon now has a solution for this use case. Details can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/role-usecase-ec2app.html