# How to download aws s3 files from client side without IAM, but only IP restriction?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to s3 and here's what I got:

I have the URL of s3 some files in my db and I want to download them in my client app with that URL (e.g. https://my_s3_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/sample_2-1591371022041.pdf).

I don't want to make it public to everyone but I don't want to make it available to only my IAM. Instead, I want to open to public to my client side web app url. i.e the file should only downloadable when the url is called from from `http://my_client_app.com`

I took reference form [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141362/amazon-s3-grant-anonymous-access-from-ip-via-bucket-policy) and made a public policy for my public ip (and the ip address of where I host `http://my_client_app.com`) but it doesn't seems working, when I open the File URL from my browser I still get 403 forbidden.

my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name_hellobucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "my_public_ip/24",
                        "my_aws_ec2_ip/24"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

ps1: if I set read access to public, i'm able to download the file with the file URL

ps2: can anyone tell me what the "Id" means / when will it be used in the bucket policy?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the bucket policy?

Comment: @jellycsc updated

Comment: As a suggestion please do not use s3:*, secondly is your application server download these images in the backend or are they being served to the user through the browser?

Comment: @mokugo-devops I was trying to make minimal change from the link I refer, but thanks! Btw user should open the file link in new window and able to download, so basically served directly through the browser if I'm not wrong.

Comment: In order to allow anonymous access, you need to set `"Principal": "*"`.

Comment: If this is the problem, the IP address will always be the users IP address. Can you provide more insight into the usecase and why it must be loaded only from a specific domain?

Comment: @mokugo-devops do you mean it's impossible to do "only allow a use to download the file from my client app" with the ip restriction method? Since it's impossible to add all ip of my users to the whitelist.

Comment: @jellycsc it works! what's the difference between `"AWS": "*"` and `"*"`?

Comment: If the download is happening on the client side then the download source is from the users browser. If the download is done server side then forwarded to the user then the IP could be restricted to the source server.

Comment: @andus TL;DR, `aws` prefix is used for authenticated AWS accounts including IAM users, roles, etc. You can read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html).

Comment: @jellycsc thankyou, based on this question, you answer is perfect, would you post an answer so I could give u the points?

Comment: However, I think I should use pre-signed urls as my final solution, thanks @mokugo-devops for the inspiration

Comment: @Andus Thanks! I'm glad it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on OP's feedback in the comment, setting `"Principal": "*"` should allow anonymous access.